# Keep UITableViewCell's background view from ignoring cell bounds

Tags: iphone, ios

we have a very customized UITableViewCell here. So it basically looks like this:

```
+----------------+
+   Image view   +
+ (230px height) +
+----------------+
+ Content        +
+ Content        +
+ Overall 340px  +
+----------------+
```

What I want to do is: Add a background image to the cell that starts where the image ends and also ends where the table cell ends (no background repetition or anything).

So this is what I did:

```
    // Custom UITableViewCell class, this is part of a method that gets called
    // in an overriden -layoutSubviews
    UIImage *watermarkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myBackground.png"];

    int watermarkWidth = watermarkImage.size.width;
    int watermarkHeight = watermarkImage.size.height;

    int watermarkX = screenWidth - watermarkWidth;
    int watermarkY = imageView.frame.size.height + 10;

    CGRect watermarkFrame = CGRectMake(watermarkX, watermarkY, watermarkWidth, watermarkHeight);

    UIImageView *watermarkImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:watermarkFrame];
    [watermarkImageView setImage:watermarkImage];

    [self setBackgroundView:watermarkImageView];
```

This works pretty well, except for the fact that the image is larger than the `CGRect` and therefore larger than the cell itself. This causes the backgroundView to overlap the cell underneath, which looks pretty ugly to be honest.

What can I do to make the backgroundView respect the cell boundaries? Setting `clipsToBounds` to YES didn't work.

Comment: on which view you have set `clipsToBounds`? on `self`(TableViewCell) or `watermarkImageView`?

Comment: I tried it on `self.backgroundView` and `watermarkImageView`. Should it be working when I set it to YES for `self` only?

Comment: I would enable clipping on `self` because the subview `backgroundView`  is too large. In addition: I would use `[[UImageView alloc] initWithImage]` and after that setting the `frame` (try also not setting the frame, because maybe the Cell also sets the frame)

Comment: Thanks thomas, set clipping on `self`did the trick. Maybe you want to post it as an answer, so I can mark it answered?

Comment: back from holiday: posted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I posted in the comments: I would enable clipping on `self` because the subview `backgroundView` is too large.

In addition: I would use

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UImageView alloc] initWithImage:]
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(...)
```

also try bot setting the frame, because maybe the Cell also sets the frame automatically of the `backgroundView`